# How to get top 150 results based on a column data

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `TEMP_TABLE` with the below data

```
SOURCE - Number
DESTINATION- Number
COUNT- Number (Total count of transactions)
SUM- Number (Total sum of transactions)
```

Sample data:

```
SOURCE    DESTINATION COUNT SUM
123123123 99009900    65    1000000
123123123 88880303    12    90000
191113111 98980101    277   5000000
191113111 77778585    5     20000
191113111 56789547    740   75000000
```

I'm trying to get Top `150 results` per `source number with the destination number` based on the value of `COUNT`. If `123123123` has 200 rows in the table with multiple destinations, I trying to get the top 150 results of `123123123` and exclude the other 50 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function to assign a number to each row (per source number) and then take only the top 150 for each one:
(Note: `sum` and `count` are reserved words in Oracle SQL. To avoid ugly escaping the example below renames them to `sum_col` and `count_col` respectively:

```
SELECT source, destination, count_col, sum_col
FROM   (SELECT source, destination, count_col, sum_col,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source
                                  ORDER BY count_col DESC) AS rn
        FROM   temp_table) t
WHERE  rn <= 150
```